# How to use querySelector to look up only direct children, without further descendants?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I select a first child of type X which is a direct descendant of the element using the elements `querySelector`

For example :

```
<div id="target">
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
   <div>
      <span>4</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to select only first child SPANs of the target div using querySelector.

```
target.querySelector('span'); // This would return all spans in target
```

The other alternatives I know and wouldn't like to use :

Using `CSS` :

```
#target > span
```

Using `JS` :

```
[].filter.call(target.children, f=>{ return f.tagName == 'SPAN' })
```

I would like to use `querySelector` anyway...

is there a way to call `querySelectorAll` on a given element, to select only first child elements?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#target > span')`.

Comment: "This would return all spans in target" No, it would return the first descendant `span` in `target`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`querySelector` gets the first element that matches the selector. Just use the direct descendant selector with it. You don't need any other pseudo selectors.

```
var target = document.querySelector("#target");
var child = target.querySelector("#target > span");
```

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to depend on the `#target` selector, you can use the [`:scope` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope):

```js
const target = document.querySelector("#target");
const child = target.querySelector(":scope > span");
```

Comment: Good, but :scope not supported by IE. (Someone might still require it.)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `:first-child` if you want to get the first child of its parent

```
target.querySelector('span:first-child');
```

Or you can use `:first-of-type` if you want to specify the type like in your case is a `span`

```
target.querySelector('span:first-of-type');
```

**See example:**

```js
var target = document.querySelector('span:first-of-type');
target.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="target">
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
   <div>
      <span>4</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for the example html but it doesn't work if a span isn't the first child. The goal of this is to get the first element of type, not a span that also happens to be :first-child.

Comment: you are right @WillReese, thanks for pointing that, i edited my answer, maybe its more clear now

Answer (score 1):

in this solution i assume you know how many item

you have to select

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("span");
 x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
 x[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
 x[2].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

the result will be the same as

```
#target > span {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target > :first-of-type');
target.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="target">
   <i>1</i>
   <span>2</span>
   <b>3</b>
   <div>
      <span>4</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Why not use this if you want to use **querySelector** anyway:

```
target.querySelector('#target span').first();
```

**OR**

```
target.querySelector('#target span:first-child');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can give an id by assigning a condition to the structures you want to search and then you can remove those elements directly under the data of the ids appointed, it worked for me.

```
const carouselIndicators = document.querySelectorAll("#topSliderSingle");
    carouselIndicators.forEach((item) => {
      item.querySelector(".carousel-indicators")?.remove();
    });
```

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the question? The question was asking for getting all the `span` children of the element, but none of the non-children `span` descendants.

Comment: I came to this page while trying to solve such a problem, I shared it so that people like me can see it. @lajos-arpad